# Using Enjoyhint with nextJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, enjoyhint

I'm trying to use EnjoyHint to make a tour for my code. but when I install library xbs-enjoyhint and using it and met an error.
Server Error
ReferenceError: CanvasRenderingContext2D is not defined.
it's in jquery.enjoyhint.js file, I don't have any idea to solve it.
Could have any way to deal with this problem. Thank you !

Comment: You will get more useful answers if you add more details about the error and project and about how you import `enjoyHint` to the project

Answer (score 0):

This package is using jquery under the hood, and it's better not to use jquery with react, by the way, insure that you add jquery to the project before using it and some other dependencies that are named on [the EnjoyHint doc.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xbs-enjoyhint)